# Perfom piping if condition is true

Tags: bash, pipe

The following Bash code works:

```
text="SPECIAL"

COND=true

if [ "$COND" = true ]; then printf "${text}"; else : ; fi | cat bar.txt - foo.txt > ./output.txt
```

It uses the [no-op colon operator](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/special-chars.html#COLON0REF).

Though, the pipe operator is being executed regardless of the condition.
I was wondering whether the pipe operator itself may be avoided - given a specific condition is true.

For example, I was hoping that something like this would work (**it doesn't work** as I want it to, rather it does something else):

```
text="SPECIAL"

COND=true

if [ "$COND" = true ]; then printf "${text}" | ; fi cat bar.txt - foo.txt > ./output.txt
```

Reason is - I want that the program which receives the pipe (i.e. `cat` in our example) **wouldn't recognize any piping** if some condition is true or false.

**Meaning - the end result should be as follows**:

If condition is true, then piping is enabled - as follows:

```
printf "${text}" | cat bar.txt - foo.txt > ./output.txt
```

If condition is false, then piping is disabled - as follows:

```
cat bar.txt - foo.txt > ./output.txt
```

Comment: The syntax of `if` is not `if condition`; it is `if command`.  Rather than using `$COND` in the example, it would be better to write `if $CMD; then ...`   (This is not directly relevant to the question, but too many people mistakenly think of `if` as `if condition`, and that mind set is incorrect.)

Answer (score 1):

Essentially this can't be done, unless you messed around with `eval`. A command is either part of pipeline, or it's not.

But in your first example, you don't need the else condition:

```
if [ "$COND" = true ]; then
    printf "${text}"
fi |
cat bar.txt - foo.txt > output.txt
```

Or even:

```
{ [[ $COND == true ]] && printf "${text}"; } |
cat bar.txt - foo.txt > output.txt
```

Both insert `$text`, only if the condition is met.

In this situation, there's also:

```
printf %s "${COND:+$text}" |
cat a.txt - b.txt
```

If `$COND` is *empty*, nothing is inserted. If `$COND` is *not empty*, `$text` is inserted.

You should also use an appropriate printf format string, like `printf %s "$text"`.

If relevant, `printf %s "${COND:+$text$'\n'}"` will also add a trailing new line.

For multiple conditions, there's also:

```
cat a.txt \
<(printf %s "${cond1:+$text1}") \
b.txt \
<(printf %s "${cond2:+$text2}") \
c.txt
```

Comment: Then I understand that it can't be done - unless using eval, which I prefer to avoid.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `cat` instead of `:` to forward stdin to the piped `cat`. This effectively "nullifies" the pipeline by passing `std` to the second `cat` as if it were not part of a pipeline.

```
if [ "$COND" = true ]; then printf "${text}"; else cat; fi | cat bar.txt - foo.txt > ./output.txt
```

- If the condition is true it writes `bar.txt`, `${text}`, and `foo.txt`.
- If it's false it writes `bar.txt`, stdin, and `foo.txt`.

Comment: I'd rather that nothing will be piped to the `cat` if the condition is either true or false. But now I understand that this isn't possible. The issue with this is that I must copy the same command twice: once with the pipe operator, another without the pipe.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than trying to massage the pipe at the call site, consider manipulating the file descriptors.  Something like:

```
#!/bin/sh

text='this is text'
trap 'rm -f "$tmpfile"' 0
tmpfile=$(mktemp)
rm "$tmpfile"
mkfifo "$tmpfile"
exec 3<&0  # Save stdin

# Conditionally use the pipe
if test "$1" = t; then
    printf '%s\n' "$text" > "$tmpfile" &
    exec 0< "$tmpfile"
fi

cat bar.txt - foo.txt > output.txt

exec 0<&3 # Restore stdin
```

Comment: Since the question is tagged bash, why not use [the `{varname}` syntax](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html#Redirections) instead of just assuming FD 3 will be available? Also, shouldn't you close the saved copy of stdin when you're done with it?

Comment: Hardcoding FD 3 is fine. In some opaque function that tries not to clobber the environment, sure, use `{varname}`. At the top level of a script, when you're not using FD 3 anywhere else, you can just hardcode it. If it happens to be open there's no harm in overwriting it.